# almost same code, cant figure it out any difference

Tags: algorithm

```
public List<List<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) {
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.add(new ArrayList<>());

    for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
        int size = result.size();
        for(int j=0; j<size; j++){
            List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>(result.get(j));
            temp.add(nums[i]);
            result.add(temp);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets/submissions/

This is my solution for Leetcode. and above algorithm works very well.

My question is that when I change some code in inner for loop like below

```
    for(int j=0; j<size; j++){
        List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>(result.get(j));
        result.add(temp.add(nums[i]));
    }
```

Then I got error like below

> error: no suitable method found for add(boolean)
>
> result.add(temp.add(nums[i]));

I can't understand why I have this error message.

First not only I can't find any difference between two but also why error msg says that add(boolean)? it should be add(int index) I think. Any wrong with here?

Answer (score 3):

Your line

```
result.add(temp.add(nums[i]));
```

is not the same as

```
temp.add(nums[i]);
result.add(temp);
```

Yours will not add `temp` to result, but the result of [`temp.add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(E)), which is a boolean (whether the element has been added to the collection, in this case always `true`).